# Override Command Button Click on the Client Side

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

How do I override the client side event handlers for the click event of the links (Edit, New, Delete, Update, Cancel) on the Command Panel within a DevExpress grid extension for ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Have you tried [ASPxClientGridView.CustomButtonClick](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_CustomButtonClicktopic) event, or this is not what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you, @Zabavsky. That is exactly what I was looking for. Just a question -- does that work even for the buttons/links on the Command panel that get created as a default implementation of DevExpress or does that work only if I create custom command buttons?

Comment: I don't know that, sorry. I guess you have to try it by yourself.